# Can subjects other than Null Pointer Exceptions be given popups on the Ask page pointing to a canonical question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, quality-filter

When I ask something about NPE, there will be a popup that says please read "[What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)"

I wonder how can I make one of my questions behave like this. When some people ask about something and they get a popup telling them to read "blah blah blah".

My guesses are:

1. Only mods can do it.
2. Questions with a lot of upvotes and locked can behave like this:
3. Questions with a lot of duplicates behave like this

Are any of these right? Please tell me!

Comment: Only SE employees can add the regex expressions that produce these kind of popups.  If you have a specific proposal that is universally applicable, not just to your question, then post a meta question about it.